# How to release camera temporary?

Tags: android, camera, android-service

My app has two services will use camera

`Service2` will throw exception because the camera is using by `Service1`

But I found some camera app, when other app open the camera, it will release the camera temporary until other app finish

How can I make the Service1 can release camera when `Service2` open the camera?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Service1.class);
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startService(intent1);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Service2.class);
    intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startService(intent2);
}
```

---

```
public class Service1 extends Service {
    Camera camera;

    public Service1() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("service1", "open camera error");
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(camera!=null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Service2 extends Service {

    Camera camera;

    public Service2() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("service2", "open camera error");
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(camera!=null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Rather than puting Camera code in both service class you should create a Camera Util and put your camera code there and check there.. is your camera is on or off..so you don't need to check is your service is running or not..

```
public boolean isCameraUsebyApp() {
    Camera camera = null;
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return true;
    } finally {
        if (camera != null) camera.release();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Actually two service is in different app, I just want to make the question simple, so I put them in one app.

Comment: why don't you release the camera if any other app use the camera